# I have 2 dates in a format that I don't know. How can I know what they are and convert them?

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have these 2 datestamps:

```
1249048011
1249049011
```

They are NOT Unix timestamps but some other format. If I convert them as Unix timestamps they are both 31st of July 2009, but in reality the first one should be somewhere in July 2015 and the second one should be somewhere in May 2015, so they must be in another format.

Any way to find what format they are in or an online convertor?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any more context?  What type of system did you get these dates from?  What kind of application is it?

Comment: it's from an ecommerce website. you can click on two option links, one returns items that have started being sold in the last 30 days(fist timestamp) and the other option returns you items that have started being sold in the last 90 days(second timestamp). It doesn't give you more date options, but if I manage to understand what date format it is in I could build in the url my own "from the last 7 days" and "from the last 15 days"

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that these don't represent dates? They may simply represent fixed options. To see whether this would work, you should try a few simple changes and see what the effects are. Does changing the differing digit to a 7 work? if so, what does it do?

Comment: I had considered it but I was hopeful that they were not fixed parameters. Your test was spot on. As soon as I change the differing digit to a 7, a 6, a 5... the website returns nothing. So I guess that is proof that they are not hackable timestamps but fixed parameters :-( Many thanks for pointing me that out ;-)

Comment: I guess the final test I will do it tomorrow, when one full day have passed. If the "from last 30 days" and "from last 90 days" use the same parameters tomorrow then that should be it :-)